# Finding the obfuscated stack trace generated by proguard

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

I created a sample app on android studio. After running proguard, the mapping file was placed on my mappings.txt file due to personal preferences. Everything seems to work fine. However, I thought my code was going to be obfuscated. My field "text" a textview has been renamed "p" according to the mappings.txt file. However when I open my project I still see the same code as before, I even set a new string on "text" and the program ran fine. Why doesn't my code seem obfuscated. I am trying to find the obfuscated stack trace, who knows where it is. By the way, I ran proguard on debug mode. Android should include videos on the ProGuard tool. It takes time from actual developing of code.

Answer (score 10):

Proguard does not change your code, it does rename the fields and method names but in the generated apk, not in your code.

You need to deobfuscate your stack trace. To do that, you can do the following steps :

1. Open /tools/proguard/bin/proguardgui.bat
2. Select ReTrace in the left column.
3. Add your mapping file and obfuscated stack trace.
4. Click ReTrace

Comment: thanks for the reply. But isn't the mapping the same as the obfuscated stack trace? Where do I find the obfuscated stack trace? I did include printusage, printmapping and printseeds on my proguard rules file. @Ashwin

Comment: The above answer is the correct answer.  An obfuscated stack trace will appear in the crash reports in the Developer console from when users are reporting crashes with your app, or in bug reports, when the APK has been obfuscated.    The mappings.txt allows the ReTrace to decode the obfuscated stack trace, by performing the reverse mapping from the trace back to your un-obfuscated source code as you see it in Android Studio.